# VIM - open file in readonly mode via :tabfind

Tags: vim, editor

The task is simple

Lets say I have a file named `Project/Sample/something.py`. I have set the path in vimrc to fetch all the files in inside the dir `Project`

If I do `:tabfind som` and press TAB key it autofills the filename(`Project/Sample/something.py`) and pressing RETURN key will open the file in edit mode.

I want to do the same task but instead of opening the file in edit mode I want it to be opened in read-only mode or view mode

I am expecting something like `:tabfind sview som` press TAB key find file and press RETURN

Is there any commands available in VIM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `:find` really does, it additionally scans all directories listed under `'path'` option. Yet the command-line completion itself is generally avaiable for all commands. So if you only need to complete file names from the current directory (see `:h :cd`, `:h 'autochdir'`, etc.), you can do

```
    :tab view <TAB>
```

or from all subdirectories too

```
    :tab view **<TAB>
```

But if you really want to scan `'path'`, AFAIK, you have nothing better then set readonly yourself. For example,

```
    :tab find +set\ ro <TAB>
```

Comment: Helped my problem. mapped to a key and works like a charm
`nnoremap <C-f>   :tab find +set\ ro`

Answer (score 1):

You can start as usual:

```
:tabfind som<Tab>
```

and then append: `| set ro` to set `:help 'readonly'`:

```
:tabfind Project/Sample/something.py | set ro
```

which is easy to map:

```
nnoremap <key> :tabfind \|set ro<S-Left><S-Left>
```

and use like this:

```
<key>som<Tab><CR>
```

Comment: Brilliant. But for some reason couldn't map. Seems like Matt's explanation works for me. Thanks for helping

Comment: @Subi `for some reason couldn't map` See `:h map-bar`. Basically, bar must be escaped to use in mapping. If I only get a coin every time I forget to do this.

Comment: @Subi sorry, I forgot to escape the bar.